# I have an index.html but I can't access it on netlify

Tags: web-deployment, netlify

Netlify name:https://jameandreu-portfolio.netlify.app/

Repo: https://github.com/jameandreu/jameandreu.github.io/tree/netlify

Hi! I'm new to netlify but I've done my enough research and still encountered the issue many of the users encountered too. When I go to my site, It says server not found. Im on mozilla firefox, linux ubuntu.

Here is the downloaded zip file from the deployment:
(you can see here that I have an index.html and in the build log at the most bottom of my post it says that
`6:12:35 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'dist'`
which is correct, I set that in my deployment settings)
[image: ZIP file built by netlify]

Here is my deployment settings:
[image: Deployment settings]

I built my site using parcel and this command `"rm -rf dist/ && PARCEL_WORKERS=0 parcel build index.html --no-source-maps --log-level verbose"` as stated [here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/site-built-with-parcel-js-it-builds-but-does-not-deploy/52358/8) this will build from my root directory and produce a dist folder containing an index.html file along with minified css and js files, It built successfully but the browser says server not found when I try to access it.
I also tried accessing it via this link https://jameandreu-portfolio.netlify.app/dist/ but the same issue occurs.

and this is the deployment log:

```
6:11:39 PM: Build ready to start
6:11:43 PM: build-image version: d2c6dbeac570350a387d832f64bc980dc964ad65 (focal)
6:11:43 PM: build-image tag: v4.8.0
6:11:43 PM: buildbot version: 4aaa27647e859c2d38cfbb25901ceae1e7f3eeae
6:11:43 PM: Building without cache
6:11:43 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
6:11:44 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
6:11:44 PM: git clone https://github.com/jameandreu/jameandreu.github.io
6:11:44 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/netlify
6:11:44 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
6:11:46 PM: Starting build script
6:11:46 PM: Installing dependencies
6:11:46 PM: Python version set to 2.7
6:11:46 PM: Downloading and installing node v16.15.0...
6:11:47 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.15.0/node-v16.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
6:11:47 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
6:11:47 PM: Checksums matched!
6:11:50 PM: Now using node v16.15.0 (npm v8.5.5)
6:11:50 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
6:11:50 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
6:11:50 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
6:11:51 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
6:11:52 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
6:11:52 PM: No npm workspaces detected
6:11:52 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
6:11:52 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
6:11:52 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.5.5
6:12:29 PM: added 231 packages, and audited 232 packages in 36s
6:12:29 PM: 81 packages are looking for funding
6:12:29 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
6:12:29 PM: found 0 vulnerabilities
6:12:29 PM: NPM modules installed
6:12:30 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
6:12:30 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
6:12:30 PM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
6:12:30 PM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
6:12:30 PM: Installing missing commands
6:12:30 PM: Verify run directory
6:12:31 PM: ​
6:12:31 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:12:31 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
6:12:31 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:12:31 PM: ​
6:12:31 PM: ❯ Version
6:12:31 PM:   @netlify/build 27.1.3
6:12:31 PM: ​
6:12:31 PM: ❯ Flags
6:12:31 PM:   baseRelDir: true
6:12:31 PM:   buildId: 62973b5bce4b0902d0f72dae
6:12:31 PM:   deployId: 62973b5bce4b0902d0f72db0
6:12:31 PM: ​
6:12:31 PM: ❯ Current directory
6:12:31 PM:   /opt/build/repo
6:12:31 PM: ​
6:12:31 PM: ❯ Config file
6:12:31 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
6:12:31 PM: ​
6:12:31 PM: ❯ Context
6:12:31 PM:   production
6:12:31 PM: ​
6:12:31 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:12:31 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
6:12:31 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:12:31 PM: ​
6:12:31 PM: $ rm -rf dist/ && PARCEL_WORKERS=0 parcel build index.html --no-source-maps --log-level verbose
6:12:31 PM: Building index.html...
6:12:32 PM: Building styles.css...
6:12:32 PM: Building swiper.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building pomodoro.png...
6:12:32 PM: Building overlay.png...
6:12:32 PM: Building background-lq.jpg...
6:12:32 PM: Building swiper.esm.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building swiper.scss...
6:12:32 PM: Building navigation.scss...
6:12:32 PM: Building pagination.scss...
6:12:32 PM: Building core.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building virtual.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building keyboard.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building mousewheel.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building navigation.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building scrollbar.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building pagination.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building parallax.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building zoom.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building lazy.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building controller.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building history.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building hash-navigation.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building autoplay.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building thumbs.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building free-mode.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building grid.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building manipulation.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-fade.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-cube.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-flip.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-coverflow.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-creative.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-cards.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building a11y.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building dom.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building get-support.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building utils.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building get-device.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building get-browser.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building resize.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building observer.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building events-emitter.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building defaults.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building index.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building moduleExtendParams.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building create-element-if-not-defined.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building classes-to-selector.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building prependSlide.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building appendSlide.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building addSlide.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building removeSlide.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building removeAllSlides.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-init.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-target.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building effect-virtual-transition-end.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building create-shadow.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building ssr-window.esm.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateSize.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateSlides.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateAutoHeight.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateSlidesOffset.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateSlidesProgress.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateProgress.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateSlidesClasses.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateActiveIndex.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building updateClickedSlide.js...
6:12:35 PM: Creating deploy upload records
6:12:32 PM: Building setTransition.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building transitionStart.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building transitionEnd.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building getTranslate.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building setTranslate.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building minTranslate.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building maxTranslate.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building translateTo.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building slideTo.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building slideToLoop.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building slideNext.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building slidePrev.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building slideReset.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building slideToClosest.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building slideToClickedSlide.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building loopCreate.js...
6:12:36 PM: Starting post processing
6:12:32 PM: Building loopFix.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building loopDestroy.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building setGrabCursor.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building unsetGrabCursor.js...
6:12:36 PM: Post processing - HTML
6:12:32 PM: Building onTouchStart.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building onTouchMove.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building onTouchEnd.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building onResize.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building onClick.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building onScroll.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building setBreakpoint.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building getBreakpoint.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building addClasses.js...
6:12:36 PM: Post processing - header rules
6:12:32 PM: Building removeClasses.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building loadImage.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building preloadImages.js...
6:12:32 PM: Building dom7.esm.js...
6:12:37 PM: Post processing - redirect rules
6:12:32 PM: Building transitionEmit.js...
6:12:32 PM: Bundling...
6:12:32 PM: Packaging index.html...
6:12:32 PM: Packaging index.[hash].css...
6:12:33 PM: Packaging index.[hash].js...
6:12:37 PM: Post processing done
6:12:33 PM: Packaging index.[hash].js...
6:12:33 PM: Packaging pomodoro.[hash].png...
6:12:33 PM: Packaging overlay.[hash].png...
6:12:33 PM: Packaging background-lq.[hash].jpg...
6:12:33 PM: Optimizing index.html...
6:12:33 PM: Optimizing index.[hash].css...
6:12:33 PM: Optimizing pomodoro.[hash].png...
6:12:33 PM: Optimizing overlay.[hash].png...
6:12:33 PM: Optimizing background-lq.[hash].jpg...
6:12:33 PM: Optimizing index.[hash].js...
6:12:33 PM: Optimizing index.[hash].js...
6:12:35 PM: ✨ Built in 3.69s
6:12:35 PM: dist/index.html                      4.54 KB    2.44s
6:12:35 PM: dist/pomodoro.0147f76d.png          37.36 KB    2.31s
6:12:35 PM: dist/index.f096b5b7.css             17.73 KB    960ms
6:12:35 PM: dist/overlay.e5753884.png           15.95 KB    2.31s
6:12:35 PM: dist/background-lq.ee603b0c.jpg    245.31 KB    2.31s
6:12:35 PM: dist/index.177d9c27.js              72.26 KB    2.34s
6:12:35 PM: dist/index.cdeefa89.js                 358 B    2.34s
6:12:35 PM: ​
6:12:35 PM: (build.command completed in 3.9s)
6:12:35 PM: ​
6:12:35 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:12:35 PM:   2. Deploy site                                                
6:12:35 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:12:35 PM: ​
6:12:35 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'dist'
6:12:35 PM: Creating deploy tree 
6:12:35 PM: 4 new files to upload
6:12:35 PM: 0 new functions to upload
6:12:36 PM: Site deploy was successfully initiated
6:12:36 PM: ​
6:12:36 PM: (Deploy site completed in 553ms)
6:12:36 PM: ​
6:12:36 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:12:36 PM:   Netlify Build Complete                                        
6:12:36 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:12:36 PM: ​
6:12:36 PM: (Netlify Build completed in 4.5s)
6:12:36 PM: Caching artifacts
6:12:36 PM: Started saving node modules
6:12:36 PM: Finished saving node modules
6:12:36 PM: Started saving build plugins
6:12:36 PM: Finished saving build plugins
6:12:36 PM: Started saving pip cache
6:12:36 PM: Finished saving pip cache
6:12:36 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
6:12:36 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
6:12:36 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
6:12:36 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
6:12:36 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
6:12:36 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
6:12:36 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
6:12:36 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
6:12:36 PM: Started saving go dependencies
6:12:36 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
6:12:37 PM: Build script success
6:12:40 PM: Site is live ✨
6:13:02 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m19.059791718s
```

I wonder what am I missing, clearly I have an index.html file, the browser should atleast display that.
I checked my dev tools but it doesn't reach the site, no response from the site thus the server not found showing. I even tried creating a netlify.toml file to override my UI settings as it seems to work [here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/page-not-found-error-on-deploying-with-netlify/32093/15). I set my publish = "dist". But the same occurs. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a currently running issue regarding this, apparently all netlify.app
domains can't be accessed from the Philippines if your ISP is SMART or PLDT.
Check this [link](https://answers.netlify.com/t/every-netlify-site-i-visit-cant-be-reached-from-the-philippines/49205/38) and [here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/i-still-cant-see-my-page-even-i-have-index-html-in-my-root-repo/64279/7) for the issue.